# how to run php file using javascript in server

Tags: javascript, php

I have tried this line  `Location.href = 'C:\Services\WitsApp.Mobi\sms.php'` and other ways I find on line but all of them are breaking

```
app.get('/sms', function(req,res){

  Location.href = 'C:\Services\WitsApp.Mobi\sms.php'

  //console.warn(req);
  console.warn(res);
  res.end("Successfully purcahsed gold for Moon!");
 });
```

Comment: you need a parser (server) to "run" php ... so href should point to an uri

Comment: Are you even running a webserver?

Comment: Also this request must be separated.

Comment: PHP only is proccessed by a webserver like apache. If you don't have one, you need it. In localhost or in a domain, you need a server

Comment: If you want to run PHP "in the browser", use Ajax to call the PHP file. Just Google some Ajax examples and you should be on your way.

Comment: vonUbisch yes I am running a websever, @donald123 can you please explain more...

Answer (score 1):

Your code only requests a browser load a PHP source file.  There's nothing within the browser that can run the code it contains - that is what a web server does, not a browser.

Comment: I just want to run the file on the server because it has a security script, I do not wanna run it on the browser...

Comment: @Ntando You will need to edit your question to provide info about your server.

Comment: @ Matthew. I managed to solve the issue last year. Thanks for your comment